# Non owning reference to deleteable object

Tags: c++, c++11

What would the best practice to hold a *non owning* reference to a object, that can be deleted?

The first part is fairly simple, I simply using the stupid-smart pointer: `observer_ptr`. However, the last part makes it somewhat more difficult.

#### Example

Having this setup, to illustrate the need of my vector unique ptr

```
class Object
{
    
};

class Derrived : public Object
{
    
};
```

With the implementation of

```
vector<nonstd::observer_ptr<Object>> _observers;
vector<unique_ptr<Object>> _objects;

auto t = make_unique<Derrived>();
_observers.push_back(nonstd::make_observer(t.get()));
_objects.push_back(move(t));

// Same objects
cout << (_observers.at(0).get() == _objects.at(0).get()) << endl;
```

#### Issue

Now at any time, somewhere, one of the objects in `_objects` might be deleted.

I will simply illustrate this by deleting the first object in the vector:

```
_objects.erase(_objects.begin());
```

This will result in the `_objects` vector is empty. However, the `_observers` vector now points to a freed memory space.

Of course, I can simply delete the observer from `_observers`, but imagine having such observing references in different parts of my program.

Would there be any cleaner solution for this, and it this the right way to observe different objects?

---

Please let me know if the example at hand does not illustrate the problem (or any problem for that matter) that I described.

Comment: How about `weak_ptr`?

Comment: References in c++ usually refer to reference types. You do not make use of references in provided snippets. It seems like a misuse of terminology to me.

Comment: This sounds like a use-case for `std::weak_ptr<...>`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl @Jodocus upvoted both! However, I have a question about this. `weak_ptr` would require me to make the object a `shared_ptr`, which **implies that it is allowed to share the ownership of the object.** I would like to imply that sharing the ownership is not the expected solution (and something else is wrong, if you want to do that). 

Would this not be possible with a `unique_ptr` (not with a `weak_ptr` obviously)?
Thanks again.

Comment: @nkmol: While accessing the object via the non-owning pointer it needs to be "pinned" (converted to a `std::shared_ptr<T>`) to avoid loosing the object via an operation on an owning pointer while accessing the non-owning pointer. Effectively, the pinning causes a second owning reference to exist: during the access the non-owning pointer is transformed into an owning pointer.  A similar system could be implemented via different smart pointer classes which don't imply sharing (although there will be temporary sharing) effectively reimplementing `std::shared_ptr` but that doesn't exist readily.

Comment: @nkmol: the need for "pinning" is more obvious in a concurrent system where the owner my surrender ownership concurrently to any access. However, even in a single-threaded system an operation can easily release an object with when weak ownership is involved and it remains advisable to pin the object. It could be done without pinning using the same mechanics as `std::shared_ptr` if necessary - I'd just recommend against doing so.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Gotcha. Thanks for explaining the "pinning" concept, have not heard about this before. This indeed seems to most accessible and easy solution. Thanks once again for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this is a typical use-case for [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr):

> `std::weak_ptr` is a smart pointer that holds a non-owning ("weak")
>   reference to an object that is managed by `std::shared_ptr`. It must be
>   converted to `std::shared_ptr` in order to access the referenced object.

Example:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
objects.push_back(make_shared<Derived>());
weak_ptr<Object> ptr{ objects.back() };
auto sh_ptr = ptr.lock(); // increase reference count if object is still alive
if(sh_ptr) { // if object was not deleted yet
   sh_ptr->doStuff(); // safely access the object, as this thread holds a valid reference
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also providing an example. I seemed to be confused about how to use this.

Comment: The possibility to convert weak_ptr into shared_ptr means that it is owning reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your use-case sounds like a `std::weak_ptr<Object>` would be suitable non-owning representation. Of course, for a `std::weak_ptr<T>` the owning representation is `std::shared_ptr<T>`. However, since you’ll need to “pin” the object before you could access a `std::weak_ptr<T>` you’d have more than one owner anyway while accessing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Today there is no way to make non-owning relationship to be enforced by compiler: 
1. weak_ptr could be converted to shared_ptr
2. Everything else could be deleted. 
3. Wrappers around weak_ptr that would be non convertible to shared_ptr would not work also: once reference to an object is retrieved it could be deleted too.